# how to update attribute parent from attribute child in xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I realy new in the XSLT world, but I have XML:

```
<Response>
<Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="A" Campaign_Status="Active" >
    <Groups Name="gplust_campaign_test_group"></Groups>
    <Groups Name="g1"><Position PositionId="1-6MOJ6"></Position></Groups>
</Campaign>
<Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="B" Campaign_Status="Active" >
    <Groups Name="g2"></Groups>
</Campaign>
<Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="C" Campaign_Status="Completed" >
</Campaign>
</Response>
```

I need to change the xml so in case a Campaign has a Position, the attribute Position_Aut should be "0" insted of "1" and ignoring all childs of the Campaign.
this is the XML resault I need:

```
<Response>
<Campaign Position_Aut="0" Campaign_Id="A" Campaign_Status="Active" ></Campaign>
<Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="B" Campaign_Status="Active" ></Campaign>
<Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="C" Campaign_Status="Completed" ></Campaign>
</Response>
```

What should the XSLT should looks like?
please please your help, if somthing is not clear please ask me.
thanks, Bakbuk.

Comment: What have you tried? We aren't going to write the XSLT for you. But we can help you with it.

Comment: What is the relationship between Campaign_Status and Position_Aut in the output?

Comment: each campaign can have number of groups, each group can have one position (but not must)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@Position_Aut[../Groups/Position]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="'0'" /> 
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...yields output...

```
<Response>
  <Campaign Position_Aut="0" Campaign_Id="A" Campaign_Status="Active">
    <Groups Name="gplust_campaign_test_group" />
    <Groups Name="g1">
      <Position PositionId="1-6MOJ6" />
    </Groups>
  </Campaign>
  <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="B" Campaign_Status="Active">
    <Groups Name="g2" />
  </Campaign>
  <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="C" Campaign_Status="Completed" />
</Response>
```

### Update

To delete the children of Campaign, include this template...

```
<xsl:template match="Campaign">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you so much Sean B. Durkin! it's great, i will try understand it and try to remove the childs. again a million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple and complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Campaign[Groups/Position]">
  <Campaign Position_Aut="0">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='Position_Aut')]"/>
  </Campaign>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Campaign/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Response>
 <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="A" Campaign_Status="Active" >
    <Groups Name="gplust_campaign_test_group"></Groups>
    <Groups Name="g1"><Position PositionId="1-6MOJ6"></Position></Groups>
 </Campaign>
 <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="B" Campaign_Status="Active" >
    <Groups Name="g2"></Groups>
 </Campaign>
 <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="C" Campaign_Status="Completed" >
 </Campaign>
</Response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Response>
   <Campaign Position_Aut="0" Campaign_Id="A" Campaign_Status="Active"/>
   <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="B" Campaign_Status="Active"/>
   <Campaign Position_Aut="1" Campaign_Id="C" Campaign_Status="Completed"/>
</Response>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use and overriding of the [**identity rule**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) -- this is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern.

Comment: thank you very much. do you know why I am missing the: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in the head of the xml after using the xslt?

Comment: @user1838563 If you want the xml decl just remove the `omit-xml-declaration` attribute from the `xsl:output`. But really, there is no advantage in the xml decl if your encoding is utf-8.

Comment: @user1838563, You aren't missing the XML declaration at all -- the values for version and encoding -- 1.0 and utf-8 -- are the default values, so `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is equivalent to it being completely omitted -- which I recommend in order to decrease space and increase readability. In case that due to some unexplainable reason you really need the XML declaration with its default values, simply remove `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` from the `<xsl:output>` instruction in the transformation.

Comment: sorry, i am missing: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> and after deleting omit-xml-declaration="yes" still i am missing the xml declaration

Comment: @user1838563, You need to add to the `<xsl:output>` instruction the attribute: `encoding="utf-16"`

Comment: thanks, but after adding it still I am missing the xml declaraion. this is what i wrote: '<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>' but in the xml it's start with: '<Response>
  ...
</Response>'

Comment: @user1838563, This means that you are using an incompliant XSLT processor (unlikely), or (most probably), the output is processed by an XMLWriter class that doesn't produce the declaration. In the last case you need to instantiate the XmlWriter with specific settings, so that it will generate the wanted XML declaration. Apart from this, I still don't see why an utf-16 encoding is necessary.

Comment: thank you! this was very helpfull, it's working now. I am using Siebel CRM component for the xslt so this is why i must have the xml declaration. again many thanx!